# How to check which files causes a https to be red?

Tags: https

Which webmaster's tool can I use to check which files cause my URL to be marked as unsafe?

I reference two scripts with HTTP and I changed that for HTTPS, but I still get the error.

Any checklist I can reference?

Tips Appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean "unsafe" or "unsave" ?

Comment: unsafe,  I happen to find the external script which were not loaded with https but with http

Answer (score 1):

You could use the network tab in the developer panel on your browser (F12). Reload your page and you could easily see which request in not safe.